# Is it alright to store frozen meat above frozen prepared foods?

Tags: food-safety, freezing

Would this cause any cross-contamination issues since the meat is frozen and wouldn't be dripping down onto any of the frozen prepared meals that have already been cooked?

Comment: Are we taking about a domestic or a commercial situation here? In the latter, sometimes there are rules to minimise risks that would be regarded as insignificant at home, so the answer may be different.

Comment: Commercial situation.

Answer (score 1):

Are you not wrapping the meat (and the prepared food)?

Wrap the meat, put them in sealable bags (*)  (ziplock type) and you should be OK.

If your meat melts in tour freezer and start dripping, then you have a bigger problem than cross-contamination, fix your freezer.

(*) or better put the meat in a vacuum bag if you have the machine to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it's OK so long as the meat is in a sealed container or bag. However, it's always preferable to place meat on a separate space because it helps prevent your frozen prepared food getting the smell of meat, not to mention the health and safety aspects of having raw meat near cooked food.